# How to Draw these dots?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can not find any information on how to draw a few dots (for Split separator slider) as shown in the first picture.

**I am trying to draw this:**

[image]

Right now, my custom control code is drawing a straight line with a shadow

```
public class CustomPaintSplitter : SplitContainer {

   ...

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   {
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;

            Rectangle r = ClientRectangle;
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), r);


            if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
            {
                SplitterWidth = 9;
                int recWidth = SplitterRectangle.Width / 3;
                Rectangle split_rect = new(SplitterRectangle.X + recWidth, SplitterRectangle.Y, SplitterRectangle.Width - recWidth, SplitterRectangle.Height);

                int x = split_rect.X;
                int y = split_rect.Y + 3;

                g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlLightLight), x, y, x, y + 2);
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlLightLight), x, y, x + recWidth, y);
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark), x, y + 2, x + recWidth, y + 2);
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(SystemColors.ControlDark), x + recWidth, y, x + recWidth, y + 2);
            }

            // Calling the base class OnPaint
            base.OnPaint(pe);
   }
}
```

[image]

How can this be achieved? I tried different Point[] methods on the internet, but none of them draw anything near what I am trying to achieve.

*Even a parameter to specify the number of "dots" drawn would be a plus.*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What it's actually drawing is conceptually clearer than your three dots.

Comment: I agree, with the exception of the main form where there are ListView's, panels, this that and the other.. it helps to not cram a thin hairline in there, and add some elegant dots adding some visual clarity. In a plain form as shown above, the line is more than acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just draw it on a panel but you can use it the same way.

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Gray);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, new Rectangle(10, 5, 5, 5));
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, new Rectangle(20, 5, 5, 5));
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, new Rectangle(30, 5, 5, 5));
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Working perfectly! Thank you so much. Small update - `using Brush b`